# how to convert date and time string to date string?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, date

I getting date like this format string "2014-02-13 13:05:16 +0000" from calendar event. Using this string how to convert like this DD/mm/YYYY format of string.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: you didn't bother to do some research on your own. did you?

Comment: See my edited answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have an instance of NSDateFormatter

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:ss +0000"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2014-02-13 17:09:16 +0000"];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/mm/YYYY"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@",dateString);
```

**Output:**
13/02/2014

Answer (score 0):

You can also do that with a little modifications on strings :

```
NSString *str = @"2014-02-13 13:05:16 +0000";
NSString *trimmedString = [str substringToIndex:10];
NSMutableString *mutableTrimmed = [trimmedString mutableCopy];
[mutableTrimmed replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@"/" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [mutableTrimmed length])];
```